# incorret number of bindings Python SQlite

Tags: sqlite, python-3.x

I have a list and I am using a for loop to add each item as a column on the same row of this table.  The list has about 60 items.  I am adding each one word at a time but it's trying to count each letter as a separate entry.  What am I doing wrong?

```
def createTable():
    queryCurs.execute('''Create Table WordLogic
    (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Noun TEXT, Verb TEXT, Adjective TEXT)''')

def addNoun(Noun):
    queryCurs.execute('''INSERT INTO WordLogic (Noun)
    VALUES (?)''',(Noun))

createTable()
for DBWord in words:
    addNoun(DBWord)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(Noun)` is `Noun`. You mean `(Noun,)` instead, which is a 1-tuple.

Comment: Thanks!  That worked.  I just needed the comma.